# AWK file to split a column into two at space

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I want to take a csv file and use AWK to split a column into two parts. The column is $11 and contains words seperated by a space.

I am trying to use

```
`awk -F ' ' -v OFS='|' '{ "$11=$11"; print }' | \`
```

I want to take column 11, split it into two using | as the delimiter, and then print the results.

The results will look like -

INPUT

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15
100|Cat|Dog|Sam|123|12345|11|G|Sam Sheparm|2121212|15*666BA  Dangers Of Cat Ownership|4/28/13|4/21/16|ACT|132132132132
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
 1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16
 100|Cat|Dog|Sam|123|12345|11|G|Sam Sheparm|2121212|15*666BA|Dangers Of Cat Ownership|4/28/13|4/21/16|ACT|132132132132
```

What is the AWK command to split a specific column, number 11, into two prices using space. Why isn't my awk command working? Column 11 is the one that looks like 15*666BA  Dangers Of Cat Ownership. I need to split that down the middle where the space is so it is two columns.

Comment: could you provide the exact input along with expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added the exact example

Comment: pls provide input and expected output separately.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added a space between the two for you. They were the same text with one showing the input and the other the output.

Comment: @Aaron Basically, you just want to split the 11th column into 2 with 1 with 15*666BA as one and the rest as one?

Comment: @BlueMoon That is all. The space would be the delimiter to crack column 15 into two parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the below awk command.

```
$ awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{sub(/ +/,"|",$11)}1' file
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15
100|Cat|Dog|Sam|123|12345|11|G|Sam Sheparm|2121212|15*666BA|Dangers Of Cat Ownership|4/28/13|4/21/16|ACT|132132132132
```

This would replace the first one or more spaces with pipe in the 11th column.